# Need help in understanding types (based on curry)

Tags: haskell, currying, partial-application

```
 curry f a b = f(a,b)
```

I thought:
the curry function takes function f a b  and returns f(a, b), so i thought the type is:

```
(a -> b -> c) -> (a, b) -> c
```

so why the type is reversed?:

```
((a, b) -> c) -> (a -> b -> c)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the source of your confusion is this passage:

> the curry function takes function f a b

Not really: `curry` takes a function, and that function is `f`. As for `a` and `b`, they are arguments that are passed to the curried function. It is easier to see that by either adding a pair of superfluous parentheses, to make the partial application more evident...

```
(curry f) a b = f (a,b)
```

... or by shifting `a` and `b` to the right-hand side with a lambda:

```
curry f = \a b -> f (a,b)
```

`f` is a function that takes a pair -- note that we give it a pair, `(a,b)`. `curry f`, on the other hand, takes the two arguments separately. That being so, the type of `curry` is indeed:

```
curry :: ((a, b) -> c) -> (a -> b -> c)
```

Answer (score 1):

Curry takes only one argument which is a function and returns a function. That argument is a function with the signature

```
((a, b) -> c)
```

i.e. a function that takes one argument: a pair of things a and b and returns another thing c. Curry does something magical to that function and turns it into a new function:

```
(a -> b -> c)
```

i.e. a function that takes two arguments: a thing a and a thing b and returns a thing c.

So the code:

```
curry f a b
```

is like:

```
let newFunction = curry(f)
newFunction a b
```

Basically curry transforms a function that takes a pair into a function that takes that pair as two arguments instead.